LDAP Authentication with Django Rest Framework
I am new to Django and i am using Django Rest Framework for Backend. I followed this tutorial to add Ldap authenrication to my Django Rest Framework project.
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ip"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "dn"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "password"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = "uid=%(user)s,tempelate"

but when i try to login i get the error
{
  "non_field_errors": [
    "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
  ]
}

Where did i go wrong.
The IP points to the correct address of Active Directory, the bind DN and Passwords are the ones i used in my Moodle Application and they work.I believe AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE corresponds to context.
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ["django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend"]

Here is the Authentication Backends.
